# Excel - workbook is slow and crashes a lot

Tags: excel, excel-2007

We have a workbook that we share with 5 users and use continuously. We have about 1800 records and 26 columns of data. The data is a mix of VLOOKUPS, standard values. I have 3 macro's running and 2 conditional formatting rules and 5 sheets with dumpdata (one containing 17K records and 40 columns of data).

We've tried to delete all extra functions we don't need and replaced them with standard text, but we don't notice a difference.

The workbook crashes continuously, even if we don't touch it and just click inside it, it will freeze up and can take upto 10 minutes before it's usable again. I also notice it uses up quite a bit of resources (CPU sometimes spikes to 100%) and when you save it uses 100% CPU.

Has anyone got a few idea on how to speed up our workbook or at least stop the file from crashing? :)

---

Called upon in Sheet1(Voice)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '43 = ok '41 = NOK

    'check if change happened in column A
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
      'check if changed value is X
      If Target.Value Like "*x*" Then
          'add datestamp if it is
          Cells(Target.Row, 43).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
      Else
      End If

      If Target.Value Like "*NOK*" Then
          Cells(Target.Row, 41).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
      Else
      End If
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Called upon in ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Set shtVO = Sheets("Voice")
endRowVO = shtVO.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Row = 2 To endRowVO
    If IsEmpty(shtVO.Cells(Row, 28).Value) = False Then
        If shtVO.Cells(Row, 3).Value <> shtVO.Cells(Row, 28).Value Then
            If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*CheckDoneDate*" Then
            Else
                shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value + "CheckDoneDate"
            End If
        Else
            If shtVO.Cells(Row, 3).Value = shtVO.Cells(Row, 28).Value Then
                If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*CheckDoneDate*" Then
                    shtVO.Cells(Row, 1) = Replace(shtVO.Cells(Row, 1), "CheckDoneDate", "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
            If shtVO.Cells(Row, 1).Value Like "*CheckDoneDate*" Then
                shtVO.Cells(Row, 1) = Replace(shtVO.Cells(Row, 1), "CheckDoneDate", "")
            End If
    End If
Next Row

End Sub
```

---

Called upon as module 1

```
Sub DateNow()

ActiveCell.Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End Sub

Sub UpdateLinks()
'
' Update Links
'
    'ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="F:\VOICE.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
    'ActiveWorkbook.CalculateFull

End Sub
```

---

**Current status:** Read my answer.

Comment: It is an Excel function. `VLOOKUP` would be another Excel function.

Comment: No, I'm not using INDRECT(). Only VLOOKUPS and IF + 3 macro's and 2 conditional formats

Comment: One possible cause has to be the macros.  Maybe post the code, and describe how they are called

Comment: Is Excel robust enough to handle a use case like this?  My guess is no.  I would not expect this to ever work well.  Although I would love to hear if someone has an experience to the contrary.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing dan :/ trying some other solutions as we speak aswell.

Comment: Try rebuilding the file to a new workbook, see http://www.theofficeexperts.com/excel.htm#FileCorruption

Comment: @dan1111: In my current work we have tons of workbooks much like this. Tens of worksheet containing VLOOKUP() (or equivalent functions) pointing to as many sheets with 1-30k lines of data.

Comment: I'd try commenting out the "onchange" event if possible. It seems a bit extreme to me to recalculate every time a cell has changed.

Comment: Excel should be able to handle this.  I have sheets that go out to XFD with VLOOKUPS and still open.  When your CPU spikes to 100% that is when it is calculating I believe.  And saving will spike the CPU also.  However, if it is an issue with too many VLOOKUPS if you are clever you can get around it.  I can post an example of my sheet that goes to XFD with VLOOKUPS if you are interested.

Comment: I don't think the VLOOKUPS are the root cause, I presume it would be the macro's, sharing the workbook with 5 users all the time, unnecessary data dumps, a cluttered file, etc.

Comment: *"sharing the workbook with 5 users all the time"*. I had missed this before. Google "Excel Shared Workbook Crash" and be horrified - I never have and never would use the sharing option. I still recommend trying to cleanse the workbook by re-birthing it as per my earlier link. But given you haven't responded to this I will move on to other questions.

Comment: brett, I have used your solution ;) I created two new files and only copied the formulas I need to be sure I didn't copy any junk. (check my answer) :)

Answer (score 2):

An Excel formula recalculates when its argument changes (or when any cell changes, if the function is volatile).

An example calculation workflow in your case would be:

- You change a cell on Voice sheet in column 1.
- All `VLOOKUP`s that refer to the data table are recalculated.
- `Worksheet_Change` is fired for the changed cell. From the handler, you amend column 41 or 43 of the same table.
- All `VLOOKUP`s that refer to the data table are recalculated.
- `Worksheet_Change` is fired for the changed cell in column 41/43. Does nothing.

Same happens on a save, for each line.

You can:

- Make the `VLOOKUP`s not look as far as the column 41, if that is possible. That would eliminate the second recalc.
- Switch to manual recalculation.

Comment: That may help a little with the speed, but not with *the workbook crashes continuously*

Comment: Couldn't it be an addition to make it less volatile to crashes? :)

Comment: @Tom 1800 records and 26 columns is a relatively small spreadsheet. Volatility goes to recalc overhead, but not to stability. I think your best bet is to try to clean your file (did you see my link about trying to fix corruption?)

Comment: @brettdj Unfortunately, Excel just loves crashing when under havy load, especially if refreshing a query table is involved. We've been there and learned that the hard way.

Comment: I haven't played greatly with Query Tables so I'm not in position to comment on that. But a few `VLOOKUP's` and going to automatic calculation is not going to cause a workbook to fall over.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possibilities

Your `Worksheet_Change` change event will cause another trigger of itself.  Its not too bad because the cells it tests are column 1 and changes in column 41/43, but would be worth fixing anyway.  May not make a lot of difference.

Also, if it is possible for sheet "Voice" cells to be changed by code when that sheet is not active, you will get unexpected results.  Add sheet qualifier to range calls to fix.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'43 = ok '41 = NOK

'check if change happened in column A
If Target.Column = 1 Then
  'check if changed value is X

  Application.EnableEvents = False  ' <-- Add This

  If Target.Value Like "*x*" Then
      'add datestamp if it is
      Me.Cells(Target.Row, 43).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") ' <---
  ' Else   <--- don't need this
  'End If
  ' --> change to ElseIf (assuming conditions are mutually exclusive)
  ElseIf Target.Value Like "*NOK*" Then
      Me.Cells(Target.Row, 41).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") ' <---
  'Else   <--- don't need this
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True  ' <-- Add This

End Sub
```

Similar for `_BeforeSave` - disable events to avoid `_Change` firing

Comment: When code in an `Event` changes a cell value, this causes the `Change` event to fire again.  In the extreme this cause an infinite cascade of events, which can crash excel.  On the surface this doesn't seem to be the issue here, but without the full ssheet it's hard to be sure.  Adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` prevents new events firing, so breaks this cascade.  Just be sure to turn it on again (safest to do it in an Error Handler)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what I did is the following, I implemented everyones solutions from creating a new file to clean it to editing the macro's so they don't handle unnecessary items (allthough I kind of don't use it anymore, I still copied it for the future!).

I split my workbook into two workbooks. One workbook with one sheet (the one we always use). This contains VLOOKUPS, other functions, button macro's and 2 conditional formatting. I removed all my dump sheets and changed the way the macro's worked (buttons instead of onchange or beforesave).

Second file became my troubleshooting file. This contains all my sheets but no macro's, no conditional formatting. The one sheet in the first workbook is displayed just using references to the cells. This file is only used for troubleshooting.

- It seems to be more efficient
- Less loading time
- Crashes less (still does but only occasionally instead of all the time :P)

Thank you all for your time and effort, I hope this is able to help out people in the future too. :)

Comment: After working with this setup for two days, I can tell you the improvements are NOTABLE! (Hardly crashes)